# Condition for using z-scores to evaluate data points

Tags: z-score

If the population is Gaussian distributed, then can you always use the z-score to see if certain data point is larger than x percentage of the population? In other words, is the method valid for a Gaussian distribution with arbitrary values of mean and standard deviation?

Comment: Quite what you're asking is unclear to me. The z-score is usually just (value $-$ mean) / SD and so a linear rescaling of the original data. By itself it needs only the justification that it is useful. If the population is Gaussian, then you expect samples to be nearly Gaussian, and the best way to assess that is a normal quantile plot (also sometimes known as a normal probability plot). That shouldn't require scaling to z scores in any decent statistical software.

Comment: I think, what OP is asking is whether for example the statement "Z=1.64 means that this value is larger than 95% of the population" is appropiate for all Gaussian distributions, regardless of mean and standard deviation. If that's the questions, then the answer is: yes, that is correct.

Comment: @LuckyPal Sure, but that doesn't mean anything about  the OP's data. It's just a mathematical fact about Gaussian distributions.

Comment: @NickCox Maybe I'm confused, but I don't see why LuckyPal is wrong. Since OP is asking about relating a particular z score to the population, then why isn't the answer simply "yes"?

Comment: @PeterFlom LuckyPal naturally isn't wrong about standard scores of Gaussians and I am agreeing with their comment. If that is indeed the OP's question, then someone can post that as an answer. Perhaps it's just me that is puzzled if that is the question, because it amounts to asking whether   standard Gaussians are standard Gaussians.

Comment: @NickCox I work with people who could easily ask this.

Comment: @LuckyPal thank you for your answer. I realized that the conversion of a Gaussian distribution to the z-distribution preserves the relative magnitude of data points in the original distribution. So one can find a critical value in the z-distribution and then find the corresponding critical value in the original distribution.